# Convert SQL query to LINQ with ToList()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to convert this SQL query to LINQ but the most I can get is joining the tables. After that I can't figure out the syntax for the WHERE part or how to return it as a list (ToList()).

```
var groups = db.ENG_Hazmanifest.SqlQuery("SELECT ENG_Hazmanifest.*, 
ENG_Locations.sitenumb FROM ENG_Hazmanifest INNER JOIN ENG_Locations ON 
ENG_Hazmanifest.site = ENG_Locations.id WHERE ENG_Hazmanifest.display = '1' 
ORDER BY ENG_Hazmanifest.pudate").ToList();
```

As far as I've gotten is:

```
var groups = from ENG_Hazmanifest in db.ENG_Hazmanifest 
                          join ENG_Locations in db.ENGI_Locations
                          on ENG_Hazmanifest.site equals ENG_Locations.id
```

What do I need to add to this to?

Comment: And you can add `where ENG_Hazmanifest.display = '1'` _before_ the `join` (and of course an appropriate `select` at the end taking the values you need).

Comment: I don't get how I'm supposed to add the select part.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
var groups = from ENG_Hazmanifest in db.ENG_Hazmanifest
                          where ENG_Hazmanifest.display == '1'
                          join ENG_Locations in db.ENGI_Locations
                          on ENG_Hazmanifest.site equals ENG_Locations.id select ENG_Hazmanifest;
```